# Adding new column that finds the highest value of corresponding non-null value in another column

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

I want to create New_Column that finds the highest number for the selected date, and returns the date, while returning null for all of the other numbers. However, if the pay_date is null for the highest number, I want the query to find the next highest number, where the pay_date is not null, and return that date in the new_column. I was thinking of adding in a case when, but wasn't sure how to incorporate it. Please find a similar table below.

```
Date         Number      Pay_date      New_Column
2021-03-18     1            null          null
2021-03-18     8            null          null
2021-03-18     20       2021-03-18      2021-03-18
2021-04-18     1            null          null
2021-04-18     7            null          null
2021-04-18     11        2021-04-18     2021-04-18   
2021-04-18     14           null           null
```

Comment: I'm a little lost on the logic.  Can you provide sample data where the new column is not `pay_date`?

Comment: Hi Gordon, the table I provided is a simplified version of the actual data. Essentially, what is happening is, the highest date is where the payment is made, however, is some cases, the highest date payment is reversed, which is why pay_date is null in the last row, so I need the new_column to refer to the next highest date.